# Django : Unable to retrieve time from bootstrap form-helper time picker

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm trying to populate a form using Django where user inputs a preferred time and location for an event.

The form was working perfect and I was able to retrieve values till I started using time-picker from bootstrap form-helper.

At this stage, I can view the UI created by bootstrap time picker and also input the time. However, Django takes this "time" as Null.

I have tried using other features of bootstrap form-helper and all of them seem to work fine except for date and time.

I have also defined below as valid time formats in `settings.py`

```
valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p', '%P', '%H:%M%A', '%H:%M %A', '%H:%M%a', '%H:%M %a','%I:%M%P', '%I:%M %P', ' %I:%M %p', '%H : %M']
```